# How to embed a custom button within a label in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've created a custom info button that I want to put inside a regular UILabel. 
The idea is to have the screen say "Tap the (BUTTON HERE) for more information". Is there a way to do this without creating two UILabels? And if creating 2 labels is the only way, how can I put everything on one line?

I tried to do (button) inside the label.text but that shows the button's properties instead of placing the button. I also tried label.addSubview(button) which works but adds the button in the wrong place.

Comment: Why not simply create a button with all that text and make all that tappable?

Comment: @PGDev Because that's lazy. Users can inadvertently click another piece of the same text. That is not what is expected. As a user I would expect that the "BUTTON HERE" part that the text is referencing is the thing that would respond to the tap; not the whole text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a UITextView with an NSAttributedString, where one of the attributes is your link.

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.delegate = self

// These allow the link to be tapped
textView.isEditable = false
textView.isScrollEnabled = false

// Removes padding that UITextView uses, making it look more like a UILabel
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
textView.textContainerInset = .zero
```

Then for the NSAttributedString

```
let text = "Tap HERE for more information"
let linkText = "HERE"

// Get range for tappable section
let linkRange = (text as NSString).range(of: linkText)

// Styling
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
]

// Actual Link!
let linkTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
    .link: "https://www.example.com" //The link you want to link to
]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
attributedString.addAttributes(linkTextAttributes, range: linkRange)
```

Then use these UITextView delegate functions

```
// Removes a lot of the actions when user selects text
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// Handle the user tapping the link however you like here
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    viewModel.urlTapped(URL)
    return false
}
```

Comment: I am trying to embed a custom button that I drew with Core graphics, not a link. The button should have a hover-type effect that shows information. How do I do this please?

Comment: Then you'll want to use two UILabels, one on each side of the button. Align their centerYAnchors or firstBaselineAnchors.